# Self M2M with django

Tags: django

I am trying to create create a M2M value on `self` within the same model. I can update the `name` field fine. However, I keep getting the `TypeError` when I update the M2M (supertag) field.

## models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    supertag = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

## serializers.py

```
        supe = tag.all()
        print(supe)
        # returns [<Tag: XYZ>, <Tag: 123>]
        for y in supe:
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            tag = Tag.objects.update(supertag__pk=y.pk)
        tag.save()
```

## error:

```
TypeError: 'supertag__pk' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I also tried just `tag = Tag.objects.update(supertag=supe)` which gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

supe is a queryset, it doesn't have a pk attribute.

Also, you are using same name for different variables. tag has already been assigned.

```
supe = tag.all()
```

When assigning tag to a new object would affect the working of the for loop, which is based on the former tag variable.

```
tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(supertag__pk=supe.pk)
```

You can't do this.

**EDIT**

The function get_or_create actually returns tuple, an object and a boolean flag.
The boolean flag specifies whether the object was created or not.
So, the logic you were implementing was wrong. As we discussed,

You could do something like this,

```
for x in supe:
    if x.taglevel == 1:
        for value in supe:
            x.tag.add(value)
            x.save()
    else:
        #your next logic
        print("No level 1")
```

Comment: Adding the `item.save()` did not help. It still gives the error for the previous line saying `supertag__pk` is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: OK so that gives me an error (using `.save()` ) saying `only non-relations and foreign keys permitted`

Comment: what is tag variable in tag.all()? could you show me that?

Comment: It's a list of dicts (I think). The print returns `[<Tag: XYZ>, <Tag: 123>]`

Comment: if its a list how does tag.all() works, list object has no attribute all??

Comment: That tells me ` Cannot resolve keyword 'supertag_pk' into field`

Comment: Are you sure tag is a list?? because the above code works just fine for me
its because you just put a single underscore after supertag, it should be supertag__pk(double underscore)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144220/discussion-between-fazil-zaid-and-ycon).